# Navigation in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, navigation

Good morning! I am novice. I have a simple JSF application. But it does not work as expected. 
This is my login.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="Please enter your login and password"/>
    <h:form id="loginForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">       
                <h:outputText value="User name"/>                   
                <h:inputText value="#{textBean.login}" required="true"/>
                <h:outputText value="Password"/>
                <h:inputSecret value="#{textBean.password}" required="true"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{textBean.doLogin}"/>
        </h:panelGrid> 
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

This is my error.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="You have entered incorrect data"/>
    <h:form id="errorForm">    
                <h:commandLink value="Back to login page" action="#{TextBean.backToLogin}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

This is my bean class TextBean.java:

public class TextBean implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String login;

private String password;

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String doLogin() {
    if ("admin".equals(login) && "mypass".equals(password)) {
        return "welcome";
    } else {
        return "error";
    }

}

public String backToLogin() {
        return "login";
}
```

}

Why the error page does not go back to the login page? When you click on the link "Back to login page" I get the exception. What am I doing wrong?
This is my exception:

```
        The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /error.xhtml @14,80 action="#{TextBean.doMyLogin}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'TextBean' resolved to null
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:521)
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /error.xhtml @14,80 action="#{TextBean.doMyLogin}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'TextBean' resolved to null
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:95)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /error.xhtml @14,80 action="#{TextBean.doMyLogin}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'TextBean' resolved to null
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
        javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
```

Help me please, dear friends! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem, why don't you just display the error messages in the same form by `<h:message>`? Forward navigation on POST requests should be avoided to all extent. You can find some pointers in this article: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html

Comment: @BalusC - Nice article:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of your bean is `textBean` not `TextBean`. That is why `JSF` can't resolve it: `identifier 'TextBean' resolved to null`